# jquery .val() method inside fetch request on dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm trying to create a reusable function that attaches click handlers to a series of dynamically created elements. This isn't the problem (I think). Most of the click handlers include fetch requests whose payload is some user input. Here is the code I've come up with. Currently, the values for both email and password inside the user object are submitted in the fetch request as undefined. Here is the code:

Parent function:

```
const addEventHandlerTo = (child, endpoint, headers, method, cb, data) => {
console.log('this is firing from ' + child + ' with method ' + method + ' to ' + endpoint);
$(document).on('click', child, function(event){
  console.log(console.table(headers), console.table(data))
  console.log(child + ' fired off a fetch to ' + endpoint);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();

  fetch(apiBaseUrl + endpoint, {
    method: method,
    headers: headers, 
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      Promise.reject(response.statusText);
    } return response.json();
  })
  .then(somethings => {
    console.log(somethings)
    cb(somethings);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

Here is the event handler for the login button that send out the fetch request:

```
addEventHandlerTo(
    '#login-button',
    'signin',
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token()
    },
    'POST',
    setTokenAndRedirect, //TODO redirect
    {'user': {
      'email': $('#login-password').val(),
      'password': $('#login-password').val()
    }}
  )
```

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Triple checked that the id matches the endpoint
2. Tried passing the email value as: getEmail(), where

   `getEmail = () => {$(document).find('#login-email')`
3. Hardcoding a dummy string into the request (which works fine).

I would love to be pointed in the right direction. I feel like the reason is that I'm not leveraging event delegation correctly in regards the dynamically added click handler (I probably shouldn't be putting the jQuery function there in the request...?). However, my brain has liquified over this issue during the past few hours, and I'm unable to figure out why I shouldn't be doing it this way and what the solution would be (ideally that maintains the structure of the parent function).

Many thanks in advance for your help. Let me know if you need more information :)

Comment: In the `getEmail = () => {$(document).find('#login-email')}` scenario, since you are using `{}` you need to use the `return` keyword. implicit return is when not using the `{}`

Comment: Also the `$('#login-password').val()` is evaluated when you bind the handler and not when you call it. So are you sure those fields are present and populated when you run the `addEventHandlerTo(...)`?

Comment: Those fields are not present- they are dynamically created when routing between pages. I need something that can do what you say, evaluated when it's called and not when it's bound. Thanks for the direction. I am still unsure how to move forward.

Comment: Have you tried the answer of @DLowther because its using a function to populate the body and that function only invoked at call time and not at bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty with jQuery, but I think the issue here is more about when in execution each piece is set rather than anything with the library used. At the time you are defining the handler the two body values are undefined, you would need to pass in the handler. I would look at abstracting out some other parts of the method, maybe something like this:

```
const makeRequest = ({endpoint, method, headers, body}) => {
  const baseUrl = 'www.example.com';
  const uri = new URL(endpoint, baseUrl);
  return fetch(uri, { method, headers, body })
    .then(response => (!response.ok) ? Promise.reject(response.statusText()) : response.json());
};

const handlerFactory = (fetchParams, callback, buildBody = null) => {
  return e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    if (buildBody !== null) {
      fetchParams.body = JSON.stringify(buildBody());
    }

    return makeRequest(fetchParams)
      .then(callback)
      .catch(err => console.error(/*please make your errors human detectable*/ err));
  }
};

const getUser = () => ({
  user: {
    email: $('#login-password').val(),
    password: $('#login-password').val(),
  }
});

const addEventHandler = (parent, delegate, fetchParams, callback, buildBody) => {
  const handler = handlerFactory(fetchParams, callback, buildBody);
  $(parent).on('click', delegate, handler);
});
```

Then to setup a method (your login example):

```
let params = {
  endpoint: 'signin',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token()
  },
  body: {},
}

addEventHandler('document', '#login-button', params, setTokenAndRedirect, getUser);
```

#### EDIT

Added `JSON.stringify()` that I missed on the first pass (Credit to below commenter :) )

Comment: Thank you so much for this- I appreciate the ES6. Unfortunately the user field is still blank in the request, possible due to the reason mentioned in an above comment.

Comment: Actually, the user field is populated (sorry for my mediocre debugging!). I believe I still need to stringify the body- but I can't seem to put JSON.stringify() in the right place.

Comment: @ScottO'Toole either in the `getUser` method stringify before returning the object, or when you call the `buildBody` like this `fetchParams.body = JSON.stringify(buildBody());`

Comment: Yep! Thanks to you all the code works. Thanks so much!!